# Render a new component from the current component after click the button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, components

I am building a login/signup/reset form. I am encountering a problem which is when on the modal of reset password, I would like to click the button to submit email for reset password. After click the button, I want a new success message modal replace the current modal. But the success message always appear below the current reset password modal. How could solve it? Thank you.

Here is the modal component of reset password

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { updatePasswordFields } from "../constants/formFields";
import FormAction from "./FormAction";
import Input from "./Input";
import MessageContent from "./Message";

const fields = updatePasswordFields;
let fieldsState = {};
fields.forEach((field) => fieldsState[(field.id = "")]);
export default function ForgotPassword() {
  const [resetPasswordState, setResetPasswordState] = useState(fieldsState);
  const [showMessage, setShowMessage] = useState(false);
  const handleChange = (e) =>
    setResetPasswordState({
      ...resetPasswordState,
      [e.target.id]: e.target.value,
    });
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setShowMessage(true);
  };

  return (
    <form className="mt-8 space-y-6" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <div className="">
        {fields.map((field) => (
          <>
            <label>{field.labelText}</label>

            <Input
              key={field.id}
              handleChange={handleChange}
              value={resetPasswordState[field.id]}
              labelText={field.labelText}
              labelFor={field.labelFor}
              id={field.id}
              name={field.name}
              type={field.type}
              isRequired={field.isRequired}
              placeholder={field.placeholder}
            />
          </>
        ))}
        <FormAction handleSubmit={handleSubmit} text="Update Password" />
        {showMessage && <MessageContent />}
      </div>
    </form>
  );
}
```

Here is the success message modal

```
import React from "react";
import { MdMarkEmailRead } from "react-icons/md";

export default function MessageContent() {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="text-sky-600 text-center w-full flex jutify-center">
        <MdMarkEmailRead size={44} />
      </div>
      <div className="text-center text-sm mb-10 max-w-[300px] mx-auto">
        We have sent the update password link to your email, please check that!
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is the result what I got so far [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRnnR.png)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I get your means..

If you want to show `MessageContent()` and hide `reset password form` in the same modal, there is an easy way to get it.

```js
export default function ForgotPassword() {
  // ellipsis...
  if (showMessage) {
    return <MessageContent />
  }

  return (
    <form ...>...</form>
  )
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the update. The modal's heading and paragraph didn't render, please see.